# Find out why server rebooted

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

I am trying to find out why my aws server keeps rebooting.

I am a developer and have very limited knowledge of administrating a server. After reading from questions on this topic in serverfault I was able to generate a log of when the server last rebooted and got these

```
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-115-gener Wed Jan  3 06:45 - 11:31  (04:45)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-115-gener Mon Jan  1 23:57 - 11:31 (1+11:34)

wtmp begins Mon Jan  1 23:57:01 2018
```

But how do I find out why this happened.

From my server usage history I find it very unlikely that a system overload caused it. Here is the output of top currently

```
top - 11:40:19 up  4:54,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 122 total,   2 running, 120 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.3 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1016284 total,   791204 used,   225080 free,   116404 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   263576 cached Mem
```

The server is a aws box running nodejs and mysql.

Comment: There have been a couple of emergency patches applied to AWS systems so it may be that. You may be better off asking AWS support although they're very slow in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your system logs and see if there are any related/relevant messages. These are usually found in `/var/log`.